# Does robots.txt prevent humans to gather data?

Tags: browser, scrapy, robots.txt

I understand that robots.txt is a file which is intended for "robots" or should I say "automated crawler". However, does it prevent a human from typing the "forbidden" page and gather the data by hand?

Maybe it's clearer with an example: I cannot crawl this page:

```
https://www.drivy.com/search?address=Gare+de+Li%C3%A8ge-Guillemins&address_source=&poi_id=&latitude=50.6251&longitude=5.5659&city_display_name=&start_date=2019-04-06&start_time=06%3A00&end_date=2019-04-07&end_time=06%3A00&country_scope=BE
```

Can I still take "manually" via the my web browser's developers tool the JSON file containing the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`robots.txt` files are guidelines, they do not prevent anyone, human or machine, from accessing any content.

The default `settings.py` file that is generated for a Scrapy project sets [`ROBOTSTXT_OBEY`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#robotstxt-obey) to `True`. You can set it to `False` if you wish.

Mind that websites may employ anti-scraping measures to prevent you from scraping those pages, nonetheless. But that is a whole other topic.

Comment: Oh ok, therefore I guess that if I use scrapy Shell for an URL. If the response appears it automatically means that my bot is respecting the robots.txt (since default is TRUE) ?

Comment: Actually, the default value of `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY` is `False` for historical reasons, but if you create a project with the `scrapy` command-line tool, the generated `settings.py` file overrides the default value and sets it to `True`. Check your `settings.py` file if you are unsure. If you do not have a `settings.py` file, then `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY` is `False`, and whatever issue your are having must be unrelated to the `robots.txt` file.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [original robots.txt specification from 1994](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html), the rules in a robots.txt only target robots (bold emphasis mine):

> WWW Robots (also called wanderers or spiders) are programs that traverse many pages in the World Wide Web by recursively retrieving linked pages.
>
> […]
>
> These incidents indicated the need for established mechanisms for WWW servers **to indicate to robots** which parts of their server should not be accessed.

So, robots are programs that automatically retrieve documents linked/referenced in other documents.

If a human retrieves a document (using a browser or some other program), or if a human feeds a list of manually collected URLs to some program (and the program doesn’t add/follow references in the retrieved documents), the rules in the robots.txt do not apply.

The FAQ "[What is a WWW robot?](http://www.robotstxt.org/faq/what.html)" confirms this:

> Normal Web browsers are not robots, because they are operated by a human, and don't automatically retrieve referenced documents (other than inline images).